# Text cleaner in OpenCV like ImageMagicK script

Tags: android, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I try to make text in image cleaner and clearer before run OCR with `tesseract`. In [this link](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php), they provided a good scripts to do it by ImageMagicK. I wonder is possible to convert this script and function into OpenCV code? For example, the script with arguments like this:

```
-g -e none -f 15 -o 20
```

From the explanation:

```
-g ...................... convert document to grayscale before enhancing
-e .... enhance ......... enhance image brightness before cleaning;
                       choices are: none, stretch or normalize; 
                       default=none
-f .... filtersize ...... size of filter used to clean background;
                       integer>0; default=15
-o .... offset .......... offset of filter in percent used to reduce noise;
                      integer>=0; default=5
```

How can I do the same in OpenCV code? As I am a newbie in OpenCV, I just only know how to convert to grayscale. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by cleaner, you mean "binarize" ? Add an example of image before/after preprocessing

Comment: Please contact me about using or converting my script to other languages. See my license conditions at the top of the script or on my home page. My email is at my web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check ImageMagick documentation to find the exact algorithms used but here is a rough guess:

```
-g ...................... convert document to grayscale before enhancing
```

That would be either [`cv::cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#void%20cvtColor%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn%29%5D) with `BGR2GRAY` conversion or even better, load directly your image in grayscale with [`cv::imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread)

```
-e .... enhance ......... enhance image brightness before cleaning;
                       choices are: none, stretch or normalize; 
                       default=none
```

Since you choosed "none", that would be nothing. Otherwise, use [`cv::equalizeHist`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=equalizehist#equalizehist) ([tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html)).

```
-f .... filtersize ...... size of filter used to clean background;
                       integer>0; default=15
-o .... offset .......... offset of filter in percent used to reduce noise;
                      integer>=0; default=5
```

My guess for the two latter parameters is [`cv::adaptiveThreshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#adaptivethreshold) with `-f` corresponding the the `blockSize` param in OpenCV and `-o` to the constant `C`. The actual adaptive thresholding methode (gaussian or mean) is what you need to check in ImageMagick documentation